# Watching Netflix in Chrome on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: google-chrome, netflix

So I know how to get Netflix Desktop and watch Netflix via Firefox.  However, I have a Google Chromecast and like to stream Netflix to my TV.  In order for me to do this, I have to be watching Netflix IN CHROME.  I have yet to find a way that actually works to get Netflix streaming in Chrome on Ubuntu 13.10.  Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but was there an issue with streaming to the Chromecast in Chrome? Or you just don't like Chrome?

Comment: I like Chrome better.  Netflix is now working in Firefox but I need it to work in Chrome so that I can stream from my computer to my TV's Chromecast.

Comment: I see. Good luck, then.

Comment: More than likely you didn't close your browser before executing the commands listed and that would make it not work properly but even after you do get pipelight to working it, I never could get it to cast even using the cast this tab its still gonna be a while anyone know when the SDK expected to hit the net or is it there already?

Answer (score 1):

Pipelight is one of the more popular solutions and my chosen one, but it will not work with chrome versions newer that version 34. From version 35 onward chrome has dropped support for the netscape plugin api, which is the api that pipe light uses. Chrome now only supports the pepper plugin api, so I am not sure that you are going to be able to find anything to make it work unless the pipe light developers decide to support the pepper api which is unlikely and netflix will hopefully be switching away from silverlight in the near future.

I know that isn't what you wanted to hear and isn't really a solution, but I thought that information might be useful.

The only thing that MIGHT work would be to run a windows version of chrome under WINE, but I'm not even sure if that is possible and it probably wouldn't run very well if at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you install pipelight with silverlight plug-in, chromium browser, user agent switcher and chromecast from google app-store, then it works.

Follow the steps explained here:

http://www.muktware.com/2014/03/watch-netflix-ubuntu-based-distributions/23091

Answer (score -1):

I haven't try this but hope it helps you, que guide is a little long and detailed so I recomend you to read once ot twice before tryin it.

[Pipelight](http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-08/pipelight-using-silverlight-in-linux-browsers.html) is project that brings Silverlight to any Linux browser that supports the Netscape Plugin API. Using it, you can use services that require Silverlight, such as Netflix, in native Linux web browsers like Firefox, Chrome or Midori.

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html

Comment: I actually red that page and did everything it asked.  Firefox now loads Netflix properly but Chrome still doesn't.